# P-Mosfets to turn on/off a BLDC motor , after the 3 phase inverter Bridge.. Will it work?

Tags: mosfet, inverter, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, mosfet-driver

I have a brushless sensorless closed-loop motor driver, like the one in the schematics. It uses a constructed virtual neutral point and some resistors to "read" the Back-EMF from the motor.

EDIT: It drives a 36V DC high speed small motor (4 ohms resistance between each phase)

[image]

I want this driver to control two equal motors, instead of only one. These motors will never be turned on at the same time, so the driver will always drive only one motor at a time, as it's intended to work.

So, could I add three P-Mosfets (would N mosfets alse be possible?), one on each phase of each motor, connected this way, like in the schematics (adapted) below? So there would be three mosfets for one motor, and three for the other motor.

[image]

So, with an extra MCU, I could set the gate high on the three mosfets of one motor and disable it,  "disconnecting it from the circuit", while setting the other three mosfets of the other motor LOW, "connecting it to the circuit", enabling it for use.

I can't mess with the driver anywhere else but in the connector for the motor cable, and also I can't get an extra driver. I need to use only the driver I have.

If I connect this way I'm thinking, would each motor work normally as if it was connected directly to each phase? Would back-emf readings also be normal, even though there are mosfets between the H-bridge circuit and the motor phases? Would the driver's circuit and motor work as there weren't a mosfet between each phase and the inverter circuit, as if they were connected directly like the first schematics?

Or... would be a better, proper, simpler or.. correct way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What voltage is on the motor drive lines?

Comment: Seeing the motor monitoring block I guess you need to be able to switch AC - relay, solid state or not, anti-serial MOSFETs, whatever.

Comment: @hearth max 36V DC, and usual current less than 1A, but could get as much as 5A in a stall condition.. although the driver stops the motor if it stalls.

Comment: @greybeard It's a 36V DC motor, not AC. I edited the question

Comment: The DC in an EC motor is at the inverter input, your question is about switching the inverter output.

Comment: @greybeard Got it. So current at each winding of the motor flows in both ways during the commutation sequence, right? That's why a single mosfet at each won't work? How to fix my idea? What's anti-serial MOSFET? Something like this? https://www.homemade-circuits.com/bidirectional-switch/

Comment: On the output bus of the PIC apply a MUX which drives two bridge inverters each for each motor . Somethng similar for feedback too.

Comment: @Franc I can’t modify the controller. I only have access to the three pin connector of the motor. So the modification has to start there…

Comment: Actually, I think just switching on/off should work with just three MOSFETs. I'm just not confident about the commutation working reliably (no sensors shown: "sensorless"?) in presence of the second motor, connected by "its" body diodes. And yes, "configuration 2" is what I was thinking of - note that it is as bad to control as the next high side switch.

Comment: I think that, if you use MOSFETs, you should apply a diode with the anode to ground between each point A, B and C and ground; choice that would be healthier for the life of the MOSFETs and the inverter. This is for each engine.